# Objdump bug (?) when disassembling a large ARM file

Tags: arm, objdump

I'm trying to disassemble libnickel.so found on my kobo (~12Mb) with arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump on a linux machine.
The file format is correctly detected as elf32-littlearm, and all opcodes are 32-bit as expected for ARM; but suddenly output aspect changes, showing non-32-bit opcodes:

=== CORRECT ARM CODE ===

```
...
4dc288: 447b6802    ldrbtmi r6, [fp], #-2050    ; 0xfffff7fe
4dc28c: 4a06b11a    bmi 6886fc <_ZN20N3BookInfoController12onBookParsedERK6Volume+0x54>
4dc290: b103589b            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xb103589b
4dc294: e8bd4798    pop {r3, r4, r7, r8, r9, sl, lr}
4dc298: f7ff4008            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xf7ff4008
4dc29c: bf00bfb3    svclt   0x0000bfb3
4dc2a0: 00627fee    rsbeq   r7, r2, lr, ror #31
4dc2a4: 00682ef2    strdeq  r2, [r8], #-226 ; 0xffffff1e    ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
4dc2a8: 0001d51c    andeq   sp, r1, ip, lsl r5
```

==== INCORRECT CODE (?) ====

```
004dc2ac <_ZN11BusyHandler10signalDoneEP8BusyData>:
4dc2ac: b5b0        push    {r4, r5, r7, lr}
4dc2ae: 4605        mov r5, r0
4dc2b0: 480d        ldr r0, [pc, #52]   ; (4dc2e8 <_ZN11BusyHandler10signalDoneEP8BusyData+0x3c>)
4dc2b2: b082        sub sp, #8
4dc2b4: af00        add r7, sp, #0
4dc2b6: f107 0408   add.w   r4, r7, #8
4dc2ba: 4478        add r0, pc
4dc2bc: 6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
4dc2be: f7d2 e884   blx 4ae3c8 <_ZN6QMutex4lockEv@plt>
...
```

Tried also on a native ARM machine, same result.
I can't figure out what's happening -- is this a bug?

Comment: The 'incorrect' code does not look incorrect.  I would expect some illegal opcodes and registers used that were not initialized.  So, I think your libnickel.so has thumb2 code.  It is possible that libraries may have a mix of machine types.  I think your understanding is not correct and objdump is decoding properly?  Also it is using PC relative addressing as you would expect from a shared library. Try  disassembling random data...

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm very noob about machine code.

Comment: the "correct" code does not look like 32 bit arm instructions.  is this an armv7 or newer full sized arm (not thumb2 extensions)?  not aarch64?